# HTML: Why i can't see elements with html legend tag in browser for mobiles?

Tags: html, css, browser, legend

[image: Browser Chrome for desktop]
[image: Browser for Android mobile]

The **first image belongs to Chrome desktop and the second is a browser for Android**, the question is because in the mobile browser (including Safari for iPhone) I can not display the legend label on the site I'm creating, the words "Area de administradores "is a legend that giving slideDown click perform as shown in the image of the desktop browser  but in the nevegador for mobiles I can not click.

Know why this error occurs? The next code belongs to the form login:

```
  <div id="content">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <legend id="leyendaAdmin">// Área de administradores</legend>
            <div class="loginIndex" >   
                <div class="titleIndex">
                    <img src="images/itcxx.png">
                    <h1>Bienvenido al<br>Centro de Información</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="inputLogin">
                    <form id="formLogin" name="formLogin" method="post" action="doLogin.php">
                        <center><h2>Iniciar sesión</h2></center>
                        <p class="fUser">
                        <input id="ncontrolLogin" name="ncontrolLogin" placeholder="Número de control" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF maxlength="8" onKeyPress="return _onlyNumber(event);"/>
                        </p>
                        <p class="fPasswd">
                            <input id="passwdLogin" name="passwdLogin" placeholder="Contraseña" type="password" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF maxlength="4" onKeyPress="return _onlyNumber(event);"/>
                        </p> 
                        <input id="bIniciar" name="bIniciar" value="Iniciar" type="submit"/>
                    </form> 
                    <br/>
                    <div id="status_msg"></div> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <legend id="leyenda">// Área de visitantes</legend>
            <button id="bSearch" name="bSearch">Realizar búsqueda</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#wrapper legend{
    text-align:left;
    background-color:#000;
    color:#F0F0F0;
    font-size:25px;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    padding:5px 0px 5px 10px;
    margin:10px 0px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
    border-top:1px solid #d9d9d9;
}
```

Comment: You have two divs with an ID of `wrapper`, that's invalid and will cause you big problems. Use a classname instead.

Comment: You are using the `legend` tag wrong. It's supposed to be used in combination with a fieldset. As [seen](http://www.htmlportal.net/tags/tag-legend.htm) [here](http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_legend_tag.cfm)

Comment: Thanks Truth and jurgemaister, ur answers worked for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two problems I can see. One was mentioned in the comments, you cannot have two elements with the same `id` attribute on one page.

The other issue may be your problem: you are using `<legend>` incorrectly.

> http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/forms.html#the-legend-element
>
> #### The legend element
>
> Contexts in which this element can be used: **As the first child of a fieldset element.**

That means that the *only* time you can use a `<legend>` is like this:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend></legend>
     <!-- content -->
 </fieldset>
```

Browsers are free to do what they with invalid markup, you may be seeing a side effect of this.

Before trying to solve problems in HTML, CSS, or JavaScript, always check your results with the [The W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/) first. Debugging broken or invalid HTML is impossible.

Comment: Yeah! is the same answer that Truth and jurgemaister, thanks :)

Comment: Did that fix the issue? CSS is pretty forgiving about duplicate `id`s, I assumed it was the invalid use of `legend`.

Comment: Yeah, that solved my problem,I add fieldset before legend and was solved, but also change id  to class if there are future mistakes!